# whats the difference between these gradle deps for and dagger/hilt compilers

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am confused about when and where to use the following android dagger hilt gradle dependencies

```
"com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler"
"com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler"
"com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler"
"androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler"
```

do i need to use them all in my android project?
what does each one do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it depends on the scenario you have in your project.

"com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler" - *This you can use if you are using dagger as dependency injector in your project.*

"com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler" or "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler" - *From both you can use any one out of two , while using Hilt as dependency injector in your project. In some documents you will find first one and in some you'll find second one .*

"androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler" - *This is an additional dependency , it is added when you want to enable dependency injection of certain classes from the androidx libraries. It is added with addition to the dependency of hilt or dagger whatever you are using in your project*.

**You have to remember Hilt is the successor of dagger and it's jetpack recommended. **

Links to check further -
[Using Hilt With Jetpack Library](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)
[Google Dagger Dependency List](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger)

Answer (score -1):

- Both Dagger and Hilt compiler "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler", "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler"" are fast dependency injectors for Android and Java (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger-compiler), https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-compiler, meaning that they serve to create instances of classes that are gonna be injected in other classes that need those dependencies; but those 2 frameworks do the job of creating dependencies in different ways. Here are some key differences;
- Dagger creates a graph to find where to get dependencies when needed in your project. For Dagger to do this we need to add the @Component annotation; although  we do not need to create this component in Hilt. Hilt already does this for us when we add the @HiltAndroidApp annotation. Also, the instance of the application can be @Injected by Hilt into other modules
- In Dagger, we create scope annotations such as ActivityScope, FragmentScope to specify the lifecycle, but hilt provides us with core components such as Application, Activity, Fragment, Service, and View.
  In Dagger, @ContributesAndroidInjector is used to automatically generate the codes of the subcomponents and remove the common codes. This causes us to write too many @Scope annotations and @Inject annotations in large projects; However, we do not need to write these annotations in Hilt. Instead, Hilt provides the @AndroidEntryPoint annotation. In this way, instances are @Injected into the required fields by Hilt.
- In the Jetpack ViewModel structure, we need to @Inject the ViewModels instance to the android components. We need ViewModelFactory and ViewModelModul for each ViewModel. At Hilt, we don’t need to write them down. Instead, it provides the @ViewModelInject and @Assisted annotation for the hilt SavedStateHandle.

Check this Medium article for futher details: https://medium.com/huawei-developers/differences-between-dagger-and-hilt-3e347d24fb86

Comment: this doesnt answer my question. i want to know when and where to use each of the listed compilers and what the difference is between them